# Передать функции значение из группы регулярки на C#

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

Помогите решить мою задачку, есть код:

```
string i_name  = dr["name"].ToString();
string descr   = dr["description"].ToString();
string pattern = @"<img src='([^<>]*?)\.([a-zA-Z]{3,4})'([^<>]*?>)";
string repl    = "<img src='" + Transliteration.Front($1) + ".$2' alt='" + i_name + "' $3>";
dr["description"] = Regex.Replace(descr, pattern, repl);
```

Мне нужно в Transliteration.Front передать значение из первой группы регулярки $1, но я не пому как. В таком виде ругается, что символ $ не предусмотрен. Если начинаю пробовать варианты с кавычками, вроде

```
string repl    = "<img src='" + Transliteration.Front(" + $1 + ") + ".$2' alt='" + i_name + "' $3>";
```

То он не подставляем значение, на выходе там получается просто 1.

Comment: А как и с чем вы матчите регулярку? В приведенном коде класс `Regex` вообще не используется.

Comment: А почему вы вообще работаете с HTML через "регулярки"?

Comment: Как это не используется? dr["description"] = Regex.Replace(descr, pattern, repl); А как мне сделать замену, если текст меняется если не регуляркой? Тут dr["description"] хранится текст с HTML разметкой.

Answer (score 1):

В вашем коде `Transliteration.Front(" + $1 + ")` выполнится до начала работы Regex.

Используйте MatchEvaluator, если вы хотите обработать группу во время подстановки.

```
dr["description"] = Regex.Replace(descr, pattern,
    m => "<img src='" + Transliteration.Front(m.Groups[1].Value) + 
           $".{m.Groups[2].Value}' alt='{i_name}' {m.Groups[3].Value}>");
```